# Fusion Slider Just keeps loading

Tags: plugins

I have a fusion slider that just continues to load.

Where this tag `<div class="fusion-slider-loading">Loading...</div>` appears, the spinning circle displays (and won't disappear).

I've read blogs about making sure fusion is up to date.  My site is at version 4.7.4  On the update page it reads:  "Your plugins are all up to date."

Anyone had a similar issue and know what I could check?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check in the developer tools if all files are being loaded and if any JS errors pop up

Comment: Thanks am_  that’s a good idea.  Unfortunately I’m new to WordPress and I can’t seem to find the developer tools.  I’m using the Avada Theme.  I’ve found a checkbox in `Avada->Theme Options -> Advanced` to “Activate Developers Mode” but that doesn’t seem to give me any new screens to look at.  I’ll keep looking though.

Comment: I don't think I have a developer tool plugin installed.  Is there one you'd recommend?

Comment: Just use the dev tools that come with chrome browser ;) https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: Right.  I used the Chrome dev tools.  Under sources, I have two plugins that show up.  But fusion isn't one of them.  I think that may be the issue...

Comment: Our website works again.  We ended up just using a revolution plugin (that was loading fine) for our slider instead of the fusion one.  Thanks am_ for helping me identify the problem.

Comment: Later we found the real cause.  Our theme was behind in it's updates.  The theme was updated, and fusion worked again.

Comment: (It wasn't obvious at first, that our theme was behind in it's updates, because it wasn't registered.)